# Align Button In Center Of Screen In Blackberry Application

Tags: blackberry

I am developing a bb application for which i want to center a button. I am not using a custom field manager.
Below is some of my code:

```
        ButtonField button;
        button=new ButtonField( "Go!" );
        add(button);
```

I will like this button to be centered on the screen. Need help. Thanks

I tried that Paul...it did not work...here is my code for the mainscreen:

```
                class Vfmdemo  extends UiApplication {
               // main method
                public static void main(String[] args) {

                Vfmdemo theApp = new Vfmdemo();
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new VFMScreen());
                theApp.enterEventDispatcher();

                }



                }

              // VFM
            class VFMScreen extends MainScreen {

           public VFMScreen(){

     // create a manager and allow scrolling when lots of fields are added
       VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);

      // add a label
     vfm.add(new LabelField("VerticalFieldManager..."));

    // add another label
    vfm.add(new LabelField("default horizontal alignment is left"));

    // add another label that takes up full screen width
   vfm.add(new LabelField("using all width & long label...",
     LabelField.ELLIPSIS | LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH));
   // add another label that takes centered horizontally
     vfm.add(new LabelField("horizontally centered...",
        Field.FIELD_HCENTER));
         vfm.add(new ButtonField("Go!!",Field.FIELD_HCENTER));
    // add vfm to screen
      add(vfm);

         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a pair of managers like this:

// Center a field on the screen using managers

```
HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(USE_ALL_HEIGHT);

VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH | FIELD_VCENTER);

vfm.add(new ButtonField("Go!", FIELD_HCENTER));

hfm.add(vfm);

add(hfm);
```

Comment: Thanks paul..but that did not display the button at all.I have included my code.

Comment: set a break point on the line vfm.add(new ButtonField("Go!", FIELD_HCENTER)); and run in debug mode, is your code running to that line?

Comment: I revamped my code and got it to center the button with the manager(code included above).The next issue is that i need to create a listener for the button.The samples i have seen do not create a listener when layout managers are used...how can i implement the button listener and use the manager at the same time?

Comment: May I suggest that you open a new question, as this has little to do with the topic of your original question. Along the lines of 'How do I create a listener for a button' with examples of what you have tried so far.